Partial completeness of second order logic
It is well-known that First Order Logic is complete, i.e. given a first order theory, every sentence which is true in every model of this theory, can be deduced from the theory, and it is similarly well known that Second Order Logic is not in general complete. However, one can still consider the deductive closure of some second order theory, and attempt to characterize it. My question is about what sorts of sentences one might find in this deductive closure. In particular, I want to know if the following types of second order sentences are deducible, if they are true:

A second order sentence which is essentially first order, i.e. all quantification (and even parameters) are of the "element type" as opposed to the "subset type". Such sentences are not obviously deducible if they are true, since it could be the case that every axiomatization of this theory contains "true" second order sentences.
A second order sentence which states the equivalence of some second order sentence to an "essentially first order" sentence. i.e. sentences of the form
$$\phi \iff \psi $$
Where $\psi$ is essentially first order. An example of a sentence of the second kind is the following:

$$\forall_{X}[X = \emptyset] \iff \forall_{x}[x\neq x]$$
Where the convention is used that upper case variables represent sets, and lowercase variables represent elements. If true sentences of the second type are deducible, then so are true sentences of the first type: Consider an essentially first order sentence $\phi$. If $\phi$ is true in each model of the theory, then so is the sentence
$$ \forall_x[x=x] \iff \phi $$
Since the latter sentence is of the second type, there is some deduction for it, since this deduction proves
$$\forall_{x}[x=x] \implies \phi$$
and $\forall_x[x=x]$ is itself deducible, by modus ponens, we can deduce $\phi$.

This depends highly on what deductive system you choose. If, however, you would like to work in a deductive system which is recursive then there is no hope. The main reason is that there is a finite set of second order formulas which only the true model of second order arithmetic $(\omega,\mathcal{P}(\omega))$ will satisfy. Such set could be the axioms of Robinson arithmetic with full set induction. The first order theory of arithmetic $\text{Th}_1(\omega)$, that is the first order formulas which $\omega$ satisfies in the language $\mathcal{L}_1=(0,S,+,\cdot,<)$ with the standard interpretation, is extremely undecidable. In fact, it is not even arithmetically definable, that is, it cannot be defined by an $\mathcal{L}_1$ formula by Tarski's undefinability of truth. But $Th_1(\omega)$ will be the first order sentences of $(\omega,\mathcal{P}(\omega))$, so if there was a recursive or even arithmetic deduction system for second order logic which would be complete then you could deduce from a finite set of axioms $\text{Th}_1(\omega)$. This contradicts the fact that $\text{Th}_1(\omega)$ is not arithmetically definable.
This tells us that any complete deductive system for second order logic must be very complicated. In fact, any such deductive system must at least be of strength $\emptyset^{(\omega)}=_T\text{Th}_1(\omega)$. There might be some clever ways of showing even greater lower bounds which would also be very interesting.
Edit: In particular, I was thinking that since second order $ZF$ set theory is categorical up to the number of large cardinals and is recursively axiomatized, it seems that the lower bound would be something truly monstrous.
